# Can we connect to the fitbit server within an azure mongodb client?

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

When I run the script with no mongoclient, I am able to retrieve the data from the fitbit server. But when I move the functionality within the mongoclient, the code starts throwing me authorization error. The server fails to authorize the credentials of the participant.

Comment: Please provide Minimal Reproducible Example as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without any code, errors, output, etc. it's difficult (or impossible) to know what your specific issue is. I'm not even sure I understand the basic premise of your question -  specifically "move the functionality within the mongoclient" - what are you moving, and from where to where? Please edit your question to contain specifics.